# Align icon before "text" button in android

Tags: android, xhtml

I would like to add a picture before the text "Accessar" within the button. As the picture below.

[image]

I got the above effect in java class, I wonder if it is possible in xhtml.

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/login.button.cadastrese"
style="@style/ButtonsLogin"
android:background="@drawable/btn_login_cadastrese"
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/icon_login_cadastrese"
android:text="@string/login.btn.cadastre" />
```

work aligned to the button, not the text

```
Spannable buttonLabel = new SpannableString(getResources().getString(R.string.login_btn_acessar));
buttonLabel.setSpan(new ImageSpan(getApplicationContext(),R.drawable.icon_login_acessar, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE), 0, 1,Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
btnLogin.setText(buttonLabel);
```

Resolves, but is much line to little effect. Thus, I have to add the string underlin _Acessar

Comment: I used a relative layout to wrap the button, and put the image to that relativelayout. In my case, this was the simpliest solution, because my icon is aligned to the left, and text of the button is aligned center. I already want to know, how we need to solve this problem.